# Unit testing asynchronous operations

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, concurrency, exception

I'm trying to unittest code that delegates work to a background executor. After I refactored a delete-method to return a list of ids, I've run into a problem in my unit tests. The tests that should validate the behavior when a method throws a sqlexception fails.

I've not used Futures in my code previously, so forgive me if this design is flawed.

The following is my code.

TaskInteractor.java:

```
public class TaskInteractor extends AbstractInteractor
    implements TaskContract.Interactor {

    private final TaskRepository mRepository;

    @Inject
    public TaskInteractor(WorkerThread workerThread, MainThread mainThread, TaskRepository repository) {
        super(workerThread, mainThread);
        this.mRepository = repository;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    @android.support.annotation.MainThread
    public void deleteTasks(@NonNull final List<Task> tasks, @NonNull final DeleteTaskCallback callback) {
        try {
        final Future<List<String>> future = mWorkerThread.execute(() ->
                mRepository.softDeleteAllInTransaction(tasks));
        mMainThread.post(() -> {
            try {
                callback.onDeleteSuccess(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Timber.e(e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
            }
        });
    } catch (final SQLiteAbortException e) {
        mMainThread.post(() -> { callback.onAbortException(e); });
        throw e;
    } catch (final SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        mMainThread.post(() -> { callback.onConstraintException(e); });
        throw e;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        mMainThread.post(() -> { callback.onFailure(e); });
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mDeleteTaskCallbackMock.onAbortException(
    <any android.database.sqlite.SQLiteAbortException>
);
-> at com.example.ui.task.ExaminationInteractorTest.whenDeleteFailWithSQLiteAbortException_shouldCallOnAbortFailureCallback(ExaminationInteractorTest.java:173)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
mDeleteTaskCallbackMock.onFailure(
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteAbortException
);
-> at com.example.ui.examination.ExaminationInteractor.lambda$deleteExaminations$8(ExaminationInteractor.java:79)
```

Here's one of my tests.

```
@Test
public void whenDeleteFailWithSQLiteConstraintException_shouldCallOnConstraintFailureCallback() throws Exception {
    doThrow(new SQLiteConstraintException()).when(mRepositoryMock).softDeleteAllInTransaction(ArgumentMatchers.<Task>anyList());

    List<Task> tasks = Arrays.asList(TEST_TASKS);

    mInteractor.deleteTasks(tasks, mDeleteTaskCallback);
    verify(mDeleteTaskCallback).onConstraintException(
        any(SQLiteConstraintException.class));
}
```

The execution is done by a test double with the following implementation.

FakeWorkerThread.java:

```
/**
* Just runs the commands without invoking other threads
*/
public class FakeWorkerThread implements WorkerThread {

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable interactor) {
        interactor.run();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> execute(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
        RunnableFuture<T> ftask = new FutureTask<T>(callable);
        execute(ftask);
        return ftask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In this snippet**:

```
try {
    final Future<List<String>> future = mWorkerThread.execute(() ->
            mRepository.softDeleteAllInTransaction(tasks));
    mMainThread.post(() -> {
        try {
            callback.onDeleteSuccess(future.get()); // LINE 1
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Timber.e(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause()); // LINE 2
        }
    });
```

You are passing a `Callable` to the worker. Any exceptions thrown by its `call()` will be wrapped in a `ExecutionException` and stored in the `Future`. 
Then, when you call `future.get()` and the task is completed, it will throw the `ExecutionException`.

So **what's happening is the following**:

1. `future.get()` throws a `ExecutionException` wrapping a `SQLiteConstraintException` (LINE 1);
2. The `SQLiteConstraintException` gets wrapped in a `RuntimeException` (LINE 2);
3. Since a `RuntimeException` doesn't match the first 2 catch clauses, it ends up being handled in the last catch: `catch (final Exception e) {}`;
4. As the output of the test suggests, `mDeleteTaskCallbackMock(RuntimeException)` gets called;

**I suggest you change to the following**:

```
try {
  callback.onDeleteSuccess(future.get());
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  Timber.e(e);
  throw e.getCause(); //<--- throw the unwrapped exception
}
```

Comment: I must buy new glasses soon. I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you for the help.